# longtable: avoiding multiple captions

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

I have some problems using `longtable` with a caption. The caption repeats every page therefore multiple entries are created in the *list of tables*.
I only want one caption per table - for the following example there should be one caption and one entry in the list of tables - not three.

How can this be achieved?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5.0}
\begin{longtable}[htb]{|p{1in}|p{1in}|}
\caption{my table}\\
    \hline 
    1 & 2 \\
    \endhead
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\endfirsthead` to define the first table heading (including a `\caption`), and `\endhead` for all other headings. See section 3 of the longtable documentation for details.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5.0}
\begin{longtable}[htb]{|p{1in}|p{1in}|}
    \caption{my table}\\
    \hline 
    1 & 2 \\
    \endfirsthead
    \hline 
    1 & 2 \\
    \endhead
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the duplication of the sections? Like a `\endsharedhead` section?

Answer (score 2):

define `\endfirsthead`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5.0}
\begin{longtable}[htb]{|p{1in}|p{1in}|}
\caption{my table}\\\hline 
        1 & 2 \\
\endfirsthead
\hline
        1 & 2 \\
    \endhead
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
    \hline  a & b  \\ \hline c & d \\ \hline e & f \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this solution `1 & 2` only appears on the second page and not at the very beginning of the table.